# Calling commands in style file located at some path

Tags: packages

Have made an `.sty` with the following

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\aluminPg}
              {\geometry{
                 paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm
                 textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm}}

\newcommand{\scandPg}
              {\geometry{
                 paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm
                 textwidth=20cm,  textheight=20cm}}

\newcommand{\ironPg}
              {\geometry{
                  paperwidth=26cm, paperheight=21cm
                  textwidth=25cm,  textheight=20cm}}
```

Have put the style file `pango.sty` in some directory.  How would I be able to call the commands (`\aluminPg`, `\scandPg`, `\ironPg`) from my document ?

Comment: place the file in a directory in the input path and then have `\usepackage{pango}  \aluminpg` in your document.

Comment: I have the library in some directory and want to include it in the input path for latex.

Comment: best to put it in a standard place (eg in texlive in `~/texmf/tex/latex`  but if it is somewhere else just set TEXINPUTS to include that. It is no different to `\usepackage{geometry}` being found and letting you use `\geometry`

Comment: When you say you want to use them in your document, where do you want to use them and is it just once in the preamble? Because if you want to use them *after* `\begin{document}` (e.g. if you want to *switch* paper sizes), I don't *think* this will work. For the simple case, where you load the package and use the command in the preamble, it will work fine. I think @DavidCarlisle 's comment is assuming that simple case, which may be right. (I know you have a bunch of questions on this and I've not read them all.)

Comment: Will use it in the preamble.  The document includes some technical drawings which require larger pages.  Which most likely would require putting them in a different document of larger size, rather than within the same document.

Comment: Is this how to specify TEXINPUTS in Bash ? `export TEXINPUTS=.:~/Opstk/Chilkat//:$TEXINPUTS`